# Communication between mobile web app and phonegap app

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-applications, mobile-application

Both applications run on same device, I would like to exchange data between the phonegap app running in background and my web app, even while offline.

Is there a way to achieve this ? I could make only a single phonegap app but I prefer to keep a web app solution for the main application.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: By platform you mean android, ios, windows phone ? The app is designed to run on any platform.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you want it to work offline, the platform is key as you will need to do some interapp communication. On iOS it's probably not possible as everything is locked down. Maybe on Android and Windows Phone